# diffrence between two sentence, Please explain it

Tags: word-meaning, tense

I am new in English, Please explain these two sentence

```
I did work

I worked
```

What is the different between these two sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is the [emphatic past](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000328.htm) and it is   formed by adding the basic present form of the verb to the past tense of the verb to do (did). This tense is used for emphasis.

The second sentence is past simple and it means that the action was completed in the past.

Comment: I worked mean's Please tell me in layman language. I have understand the first one "I did work" but not second one, what you mean's by emphasis ?

Comment: emphasis means special importance or significance: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/emphasis

Answer (score 1):

*Work* is a word that can be used as a verb or a noun. (Just [look it up](http://www.onelook.com/?w=work&ls=a), and you'll find it's true!)

In the sentence:

> *I worked.*

it's clearly a verb. In the sentence

> *I did work.*

it could be a noun, particularly if we expand the sentence some:

> *I did some work on the bathroom floor before I put up new ceiling tiles in the living room*.

However, the word *work* could also be part of a two-word verbal phrase functioning in the past tense:

> Did you work yesterday?
>   *I did work yesterday, from 6:30 until 10:30. That's why I got home so late*.

Comment: Out of curiosity: if there’s not any article or quantifier how can we distinguish whether it’s a noun?

Comment: @LucianSava By the role it plays in the sentence, and in speech by intonation.

Comment: @StoneyB, thank you but I think I'd never get those tough things.

Comment: @LucianSava In the final example, when spoken, special emphasis would be placed on "did", as in, "I *did* work yesterday, from 6:30 until 10:30." (spoken with slight emphasis and raised pitch). This stress on "did" decouples it from "work" and so it's no longer taken as a two-word verbal phrase - but sometimes this understanding only comes with familiarity with the language, and it certainly can be confusing. If you do not like the ambiguity I suppose you could instead answer e.g., "Yes, I did, from 6:30 until 10:30."

Comment: @JasonC, thank you for clarifying my dilema. Now, I think I can see the difference.